# java rest web service using post method

Tags: java

I am trying to do a java rest web service using "POST" method.My client part to invoke the web service is working proper.But i am facing difficulty in accessing the passed parameters by "POST" method.Any help would be appreciable. Here is my client side

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String urlParameters = "param1=world&param2=abc";

    String request = "http://localhost:8080/wsRevDash/rest/post/test";

    URL url = new URL(request);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);

    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

And here is my java rest web service

```
   @POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)


    public String getpostdata(@QueryParam("param1") String param1,@QueryParam("param2") String param2)
    {

        JSONObject jObjDevice = new JSONObject();

         jObjDevice.put("Hello",param1);
         return jObjDevice.toJSONString();

     }
```

The parameter param1=world.But when i run the web service,I am getting json string as {"Hello":null} instead of {"Hello":"world"}.Please suggest for any changes.I think the problem is with annotation i.e @QueryParam.If this is the case,then please provide proper way to access the parameter using proper annotation.

Comment: Please Add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotation and give it a single JSON object instead of a two strings as a post method arguments.

Comment: So,there is no way to run the web service using  different strings as a post method arguments?

Comment: Please someone help me in doing this way only as it is simple,if possible.